# vim spell checker?

Tags: vim, spell-checking

Is there a way to spell check a file using vim?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have a spell checker installed on your system, vim will usually find it. If not you will need to install `ispell`, `aspell`, `hunspell` or a similar system as well as support files for the language you want to check.

```
:set spell
```

Here is [an answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640351/how-can-i-spellcheck-in-gvim/640362#640362) with keybindings and also a [quick little tutorial](http://tips.webdesign10.com/vim/how-use-vims-spellchecker) for usage.

Comment: Also, you can add the `:set spell` in ~/.vimrc file, so that it will be effective for all the file.

Comment: `quick little tutorial` link is dead at the time of writing.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to toggle spellcheck on and off, you can add something like the following to your .vimrc:

```
map <F4> :setlocal spell spelllang=en_gb<CR>
map <F5> :set nospell<CR>
```